# Iterating through a List of Arrays and printing every element within the Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iterator

I seem to be having trouble in the logic of my problem. What I am trying to do is have a List of Arrays. Each Array contains 2 String.

I am trying to iterate through my List and then printing the elements of the arrays. I seem to get stuck in printing the first Array (which is what my code does), though I am stuck in the logic.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> addresses = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> singleAddress1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    singleAddress1.add("17 Fake Street");
    singleAddress1.add("18 Fake Street");
    ArrayList<String> singleAddress2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    singleAddress2.add("Phoney town");
    singleAddress2.add("not real town");
    ArrayList<String> singleAddress3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    singleAddress3.add("sillyname town");
    singleAddress3.add("alsosilly town");
    addresses.add(singleAddress1);
    addresses.add(singleAddress2);
    addresses.add(singleAddress3);

    System.out.print("Original contents of al: " + addresses + "\n");
    Iterator itr = addresses.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object element = itr.next();
        System.out.print(element + "\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < singleAddress1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(singleAddress1.get(i));
        }
        itr.remove();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what errors are you gettingg? for one thing i notice is in the inner for loop you are not using element but singleaddress1

Comment: 1) You have a list of lists, not a list of array. 2) you always print the elements from list `singleAddress1` instead of the elements from list returned by `itr.next()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you are iterating over the outer array list `addresses`, internally you end up iterating on same `singleAddress1` instead of all the list elements which you would get from iterator using `for (int i = 0; i < singleAddress1.size(); i++) {`.

Your iteration loop should be:

```
Iterator<List<String>> itr = addresses.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    List<String> element = itr.next();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    System.out.print(element + "\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++) {
                        ^^^^^^^^
        System.out.println(element.get(i));
    }
    itr.remove();
}
```

Comment: wont it show an error in itr.next() because that returns an object and we need to typecast it

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer to my question. Thank you. I did notice I was only getting items from singleAddress1. The logic is sound. I did not know I could Use an Iterator on a List<String> aswel. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a simple `for-each` loop:

```
for(List<String> list:addresses)
{
    for(String str:list)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: See that OP is deleting the entry as well using `itr.remove()`

Comment: @SMA yes i know :)
i thought maybe OP was just doing it to make the loop work